# onClick listener is not working in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

My xml code,

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/help_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/welcome_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcome_to_lb" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="87dp"
            android:layout_height="88dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/help_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/help_paragraph" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/help_overview_btn"
            style="@style/help_overview_btn"
            android:layout_width="93dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/overview" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Listener code,

```
  Button overViewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.help_overview_btn);
    overViewButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>> onClick >>>>>>>>>>");
        }
    });
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: what do you see in the logcat?

Comment: please post whole xml

Comment: Must sure that your **onClickListener** imported as a **import android.view.View.OnClickListener;**

Comment: logcat did't display anything when i do click?

Comment: @sasikkumar your code looks alright. post the activity code full

Comment: @sasikkumar post your complete xml code

Comment: @PiyushGupta if it is not `View.OnClickListener`, OP will get compile time error...

Comment: @sasikkumar Please clearify your question properly with your logcat and proper code.

Comment: post your whole activity as well as xml.

Comment: Where is your listener code? In your onCreate or some other place?

Comment: Have you tried with Toast message on the place of System.print

Comment: @sasikkumar Post your full Activity code.

Comment: @sasikkumar your onclick listener is working well here

Comment: I've occasionally had problems where the compiled resources have got out of sync (using Eclipse ADK) so the view being returned by findViewById() isn't what I was expecting. Performing a Clean (I think it is from the Run menu) rebuilds the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports, could you found this:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

I think you have imported something else. Please check it anf if not then please import this one. Your click will work.

Comment: If i did't import it. i will get compile time error. But i did't get compile time error. also other buttons listener are working fine.

Comment: is there this import or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are coming from Java to Android.
Because

> System.out.println()

won't work in Android like the way it works in Java, since there is no console to send the messages to so the System.out.println messages will be sent to Logcat. Please be sure to check in Logcat with info dropdown selected.

Instead, you can use the [Android Log class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html):

```
Log.d("MyApp",">>>>>>>>>> onClick >>>>>>>>>>");
```

There are five one-letter methods in Log corresponding to the following levels:

> e() - Error
>
> w() - Warning
>
> i() - Information
>
> d() - Debug
>
> v() - Verbose

Comment: Log also has a 6th level, my favourite - Log.wtf()

Answer (score 0):

Please update your xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/help_overview_btn"
        style="@style/help_overview_btn"
        android:layout_width="93dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="overViewOnclick"
        android:background="@drawable/overview" />
```

And add code for listener

```
public void overViewOnclick(View view){
//write your code here
Toast.makeText(this, ">>>>>>>>>> onClick >>>>>>>>>>", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Hope this will help you